# Audio issues when overlaying two videos (ffmpeg)

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay a short 10 second video on top of a 2 minute video and have the 10 second video show up at the 30 second mark. Here is what I have so far

```
start = 30
subprocess.run(
    f'ffmpeg -y \
        -i {os.path.join(path, "2minutevideo.mp4")} \
        -i {os.path.join(path, "popup.mov")} \
        -filter_complex \
        "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
        [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+{notify_start}/TB[v1]; \
        [v0][v1]overlay=enable=\'between(t, {notify_start}, {notify_start + get_duration(os.path.join(path, "popup.mp4"))})\' [out1]" \
        {render_flags} -r 24 -map 1:a -map [out1] -async 1 \
        {os.path.join(source_folder, "test.mp4")}')
```

What this does is that popup.mov shows up at 30 seconds and plays for its entire duration. However, I have two issues:

1. popup.mov's audio still plays at the beginning. I've tried itsoffset, setting the pts but both seem to not work or have errors.
2. The only audio playing is popup.mov's audio. I would like both 2minutevideo and popup.mov to play audio. Yes, I'm aware it's because -map 1:a only maps the popup's audio to the final video, but I have no idea how to have both audio play. Would I have to mix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters:

```
start = 30
subprocess.run(
    f'ffmpeg -y \
        -i {os.path.join(path, "2minutevideo.mp4")} \
        -i {os.path.join(path, "popup.mov")} \
        -filter_complex \
        "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
        [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+{notify_start}/TB[v1]; \
        [v0][v1]overlay=enable=\'between(t, {notify_start}, {notify_start + get_duration(os.path.join(path, "popup.mp4"))})\' [out1]; \
        [1:a]adelay={notify_start}s:all=1[a1];[0:a][a1]amix[a]"
        {render_flags} -r 24 -map [out1] -map [a] -async 1 \
        {os.path.join(source_folder, "test.mp4")}')
```

This is purely a ffmpeg question. The python code is just noise. You may have have gotten an answer faster if there wasn't any python in the way.